# How to login successfully with details from an array in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

How to stop looping once the `uninput` and `pwinput` matches with the array from LocalStorage?

```js
function login() {
  existinglist = JSON.parse(localStorage["existinglist"]);
  var uninput = document.getElementById('UserName').value;
  var pwinput = document.getElementById('PassWord').value;
  for (var i = 0; i < existinglist.length; i++) {
    if (uninput == existinglist[i]['UserName'] && pwinput == existinglist[i]['Password']) {
      credential
      alert('You have login successfully!');
      break;
    } else {
      alert('Invalid login!');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="             " class="loginform" onsubmit=' return login()'>
  <label>Username: </label>
  <input type="text" id='UserName' name="UserName" autocomplete='off' required>
  <label>Password: </label>
  <input type="password" id='PassWord' name="PassWord" autocomplete='off' required>

  <button type="submit">Log in</button>


</form>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ybgw4vdc/2/ pls take a look over here sorry

Comment: Why are you doing login from localStorage anyway?

Comment: If you don't want your form to be submitted, your `login` function must return `false`

Comment: What is `credential` supposed to do? Also, It's a very bad practice to store passwords and usernames in `localStorage`.

Comment: i am trying to learn thats why im using localstorage

Comment: just ignore the credential  sorry

Comment: I think what you're looking for is how to stop form submission based on whatever validation must be done.
Look here for information on how to stop form submission: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664486/javascript-code-to-stop-form-submission

Comment: https://ibb.co/cAkUio this is image link of the values stored in localstorage

Comment: I wanted to compare the entered values with the localStorage data that is in an array

Comment: That is not how you use localStorage. Use the `getItem` method.

Answer (score 0):

Your second page for creating a user account does't exist. Your code will work, provided it is in a function and you remove those  tags

Comment: This is not an answer, but something that should go in a comment

Comment: My bad, can't post comments

Comment: Oh I understand